# Stopping a form redirect using AJAX error

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, redirect

trying to make it so my form doesn't redirect when the user enters their email and hits the OK button.

I seem to have the AJAX code itself working as the error message displays but my issue is that it errors every time as well as displays the error message 3 times over.

Here's the code snippet

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).scroll(function () {
                var $nav = $(".navbar-fixed-top");
                $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
            });
            $('.count').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 7000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $form = $('.newsletter');
                    if ($form.length > 0) {
                        $('form input[type="submit"]').bind('click', function (event) {
                            if (event) event.preventDefault();
                            register($form);
                        });
                    }
                });

                function register($form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: $form.attr('method'),
                        url: $form.attr('action'),
                        data: $form.serialize(),
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert(
                                "Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later."
                            );
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.result != "success") {
                                // Something went wrong, do something to notify the user. maybe alert(data.msg);
                            } else {
                                // It worked, carry on...
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.customer-logos').slick({
                        slidesToShow: 4,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
                        arrows: false,
                        dots: false,
                        pauseOnHover: false,
                        responsive: [{
                            breakpoint: 768,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 4
                            }
                        }, {
                            breakpoint: 520,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top-bg" style="position:relative;">
        <p class="text-uppercase-1" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="900" data-aos-delay="100" data-aos-once="true"
            data-aos-easing="ease-in-out" id="top-banner-text-1" style="font-family:Karla, sans-serif;">AIRBNB CARES</p>
        <form class="newsletter" action="https://airbnbcares.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST"
            autocomplete="off">
            <input type="hidden" name="u" value="88baf6d86f9a8faebb5c5ec99">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="774141a683">
            <input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Enter your email address to subscribe!" tabindex="1"
                class="newsletter-email" required>
            <input type="submit" class="newsletter-submit" name="submit" value="OK">
        </form>
    </div>
```

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: try prevent default  use this link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Answer (score 1):

You may change blind button 'click' to form 'submit'

```
$('form').bind('submit', function (event) {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    register($form);
});
```

Or change input type 'submit' to 'button' (but your form will not send data name 'submit')

```
<input type="button" class="newsletter-submit" name="submit" value="OK">
```

Comment: Changing 'click' to 'submit' makes the page redirect for some reason.

Comment: I tried this a bit further and it's working (seemingly) but only displaying the error message meaning the emails aren't actually going through. Any insight as to why this might be?

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end of function `register` same as @Banujan Balendrakumar said, will work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    var $form = $('.newsletter');
                    if ($form.length > 0) {
                        $('form input[type="submit"]').bind('click', function (event) {
                            if (event) event.preventDefault();
                            register($form);
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Edit

```
<form class="newsletter" action="https://airbnbcares.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
```

To

Add `return false;` at the end for the `function register`

```
    function register($form) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: $form.attr('method'),
                            url: $form.attr('action'),
                            data: $form.serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            error: function (err) {
                                alert(
                                    "Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later."
                                );
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.result != "success") {
                                    // Something went wrong, do something to notify the user. maybe alert(data.msg);
                                } else {
                                    // It worked, carry on...
                                }
                            }
                        });

return false;                    

}
```

Comment: This also still redirects me to the page.. I'm not quite sure why. The other code at least displayed the error text.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to prevent other event handlers from executing after a certain event is fired, use

> **event.preventDefault();**

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    // do your things ...

});
```

Comment: How would I go about implementing this into the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. But the target URL won't allow XML-HTTP request bcoz of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="newsletter" onsubmit="return sendData();"autocomplete="off" id='myform'>
            <input type="hidden" name="u" value="88baf6d86f9a8faebb5c5ec99">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="774141a683">
            <input type="email" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Enter your email address to subscribe!" tabindex="1"
                class="newsletter-email" required>
            <input type="submit" class="newsletter-submit" name="submit" value="OK">
        </form>
        
<script>
        
function sendData(){

var formData = $("#myform").serialize();

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            
            var response = this.responseText;
            
            if(response == "success"){
            
              alert("done");
            
            }else{
            
              alert("faild");
            
            }
       }
};

xhttp.open("POST", "https://airbnbcares.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send(formData);

return false;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to send the email to the mailchimp list. It just does nothing.. Is this because of the XML-HTTP request?

Comment: Yes. They are not allowing XML-HTTP request from out side

Comment: And your tokens are expired.